# How to post an image/video/audio to Tumblr's API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, tumblr

So, I've managed to post quotes, texts, links, etc. to Tumblr's API, but I'm wondering how one would go about posting images, videos and audio to their API. I assume posting from a web URL should be easy, but how would you go about posting these assets, for example, from your local file system?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting for example as you can see for "Photo Posts" you can specifiy image by source or data or data64.
I think that data64 is a base64 string containing your image. So you just have to base64 your image then made a request to post it.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but was trying to figure out how to convert an image/audio/video to their needed format.

Comment: If i'm right the data is base64 encoded, depending of what language you use, you have php base64encode and base64decode method. In javascript you have atob and btoa. You can also try [link](https://www.base64encode.org) Try to convert you media in base64 and to send to the server.

Comment: Also for ```video``` based posts, you have to use ```data64``` as well. The documentation states using the ```data``` parameter, but it is wrong.